# Is $I-2T$ self-adjoint for a rank-one operator $\,Tx=\langle\,x\mid u\,\rangle u\,$ on Hilbert space with $\|u\|=1$?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

I understand the definition of self-adjoint in terms of the inner product, but I am not sure how to do this as we are not given the inner product for the operator.

I'm sure that I have to use the norm at some point, since $u$ is a unit vector, but again not sure how I can make use of this without knowing the inner product.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a good starting point is to recall the defining property of the adjoint $T^*$ of an operator $T$
$$\langle\,Tx\mid y\,\rangle\;=\;\langle\,x\mid T^*y\,\rangle\quad\forall x,y\in H.$$
It involves the given operator and the scalar product while $x$ and $y$ run through all of $H$.

Now apply this to a rank-one operator $T$, thus
$Tx=\langle x|u\rangle\,v\,$ with fixed $\,u,v\in H$,
to find its adjoint:
$$\langle\,Tx\mid y\,\rangle\;=\;
\langle\,\langle x| u\rangle v\mid y\,\rangle\;=\;
\langle x| u\rangle\:\langle v|y\rangle\;=\;
\langle\,x\mid \langle y|v\rangle u\,\rangle
\quad\forall x,y\in H,$$
hence $T^*y=\langle y|v\rangle\,u$. Compared with $T$, the vectors $u$ and $v$ are swapped.

*In particular $T$ is self-adjoint if $\,v=u$.*

Note that if $u$ is a unit vector then $x\mapsto\langle x|u\rangle u\,$ is the orthogonal projector onto the subspace $\mathbb Cu$.

Answer (score 0):

Direct computation gives
\begin{align*}
\left<(I-2T)x,y\right>=\left<x,y\right>-2\left<x,u\right>\left<u,y\right>
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\left<x,(I-2T)y\right>=\left<x,y\right>-2\left<u,y\right>\left<x,u\right>.
\end{align*}